# Who is the Rishi Samharabhairava?

Tags: rishi

The [banalinga kavacham](https://sthothramala.blogspot.com/2018/07/sri-banalinga-kavacham-lyrics-and.html) discusses one Rishi Samharabhairava (संहारभैरवऋषि) in the beginning, but I can't find any information about who he was. It seems that he himself wrote that mantra. I know of an 'Ananda Bhairava Rishi', but that is probably a different person.

So who is the Rishi Samharabhairava?

Comment: Samhara Bhairava is a deity .. one among the 8 Bhairavas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashta_Bhairava) to be precise .. Rishi of a mantra does not have to be a Rishi (saint) .. deities can be Rishi too .. Lord Sadashiva is the Rishi for various mantras for e.g.